# Generating historical reports in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, reporting

I am looking to generate historical reports for a rails site that vary in granularity based on time ago. For example, if I was interested in the distribution of user.last_signed_in, I should be able to look at that chart for today, 1 week ago, 1 month ago, 1 year ago etc.

Is there an easy way to approach this problem? I could use something like vestal_versions, but that stores too much information and would be a pain to extract from.